# When is an inclusion map, infinitely differentiable?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x=2y+z\}$, which is just a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$

The question says to create an atlas on $A$ such that the inclusion map is a $C^\infty$-map.

If I understand correctly, this depends entirely on how you structure the $U_i$ in the atlas: $\{(U_i, \phi_i)\}$?

You'd want the $U_i$ to be overlapping intervals (on the line above), right?

A valid atlas would be simply $\{(A,id)\}$ with $id$ being the identity map.

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: You need a chart to be homeomorphic to an open subset of some $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So you can use $A$ as a chart, but you need something other than the identity map.

Comment: This is not a line!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry. I meant to write some equation of a line. It's just a made up example but ended up with a plane.

Comment: @D_S Yes, I see now. I misread my notes.

Comment: @D_S but the identity map is a homeomorphism still, right? It's a bijection and it is equal to it's inverse map, and the map is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Yeah but the image of the identity map is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: And calling something infinitely differentiable makes no sense without an existing manifold structure, i.e. reduction to talking about smooth maps between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for various $n$.

Comment: @ D_S so you need to find an open cover of the plane $A$, $A=\cup A_i$ such that each $A_i$ is open. Then $\{(A_i,id_i)\}$ would be your atlas with each identity restricted to an open set $A_i$. Is that it?

Comment: That's not quite it.  Again you can't use the identity map.

Comment: @D_S I don't understand, then. Why does the question ask for the inclusion? Can the inclusion be something else other than the identity map?

Comment: The point is that $A$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @D_S Yes, but then how can you write an atlas of $A$ and I still don't understand what the inclusion has to do with anything if you cannot use it?

Comment: @D_S Ok so have $\phi_i$ which maps $A_i$ to itself but is not the identity. Suppose $\phi_i$ is homeomorphic too. That would suffice as an atlas, then, right? Since $A_i$ are open. But then what does the inclusion have to do with anything? Is the question maybe asking for $A_i$ to be such that the inclusion is infinitely differentiable over all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space, an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold structure on $X$ is a collection of open sets $U_i$ covering $X$, together with homeomorphisms $\phi_i$ of $U_i$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that for all $i,j$ the compositions

$$\mathbb{R}^n \supseteq \phi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \rightarrow U_i \cap U_j \rightarrow \phi_j(U_i \cap U_j) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$$

are diffeomorphisms.  (Compatibility between charts)  The pairs $(U_i,\phi_i)$ are called charts.

Your topological space in this case is $X = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x = 2y + z \}$ with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^3$.  You can see that $X$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So it does not make sense to talk about the inclusion map $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ being smooth (infinitely differentiable) without first putting a manifold structure on $X$.

Note that $X = \{ (x,y,x-2y) : x, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

I claim that there is a natural structure of a $2$-dimensional manifold on $X$.  Namely, take the collection of open subsets of $X$ covering $X$ to just be the open set $X$ (open in itself).    And define a map $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\phi(x,y,z) = (x,y)$.  It is easy to see that $\phi$ is a continuous bijection onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (namely onto the open set $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself).  Also, the inverse map $\phi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow X$ is continuous.  So $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Thus we have a chart $(X,\phi)$, where $X$ is an open subset of $X$, and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Since we have only one chart, there is nothing to check for compatibility.  Therefore $X$, together with the single chart $(X,\phi)$, is a smooth $2$-dimensional manifold.

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function between $n$ and $m$ dimensional manifolds.  By *definition*, $f$ is smooth if there exist charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ of $X$, covering $X$, and charts $(V_i,\psi_i)$ of $Y$, such that $f(U_i) \subseteq V_i$, and such that each composition

$$\phi_i(U_i) \xrightarrow{\phi_i^{-1}} U_i \xrightarrow{f} V_i\xrightarrow{\psi_i} \psi_i(V_i)$$
is smooth as a map from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Now $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are manifolds, so I'll leave it to you to check that the inclusion map $i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is smooth.

Comment: @D_M This was really helpful. Thanks a lot. So the inclusion bit is just checking that $(\phi_i \circ i)(U_i)$ are smooth, right? And $X$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but open in itself.

Comment: Right.  Checking smoothness of a map between manifolds always comes down to checking that maps between *open* sets of Euclidean space are smooth.